libmariadb-dev alternative for rhel 9
What is the alternative package for libmariadb-dev from ubuntu on rhel 9? When we are compiling project on ubuntu, we use
#include <mariadb/mysql.h> 

which is problematic on rhel, because every mariadb package that I found creates only mysql/mysql.h.

yum install MariaDB-shared MariaDB-devel? https://mariadb.com/docs/server/connect/programming-languages/c/install/#Installation_via_Package_Repository_(Linux)

@OneCricketeer this installs only /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h  and /usr/include/mysql/server/mysql.h, we are using /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h.
